# rails -v returns incorrect ruby version

Tags: ruby, macos, ruby-on-rails-4, rvm, rbenv

I previously used rvm on my Mac to manage Ruby for a RoR app running Ruby =2.1.2 and Rails 4.0.3. I installed rbenv via homebrew before realizing it would conflict with rvm. In rbenv I installed Ruby 2.4.0, but then deleted it and uninstalled rbenv. Even after removing rbenv rails -v started giving me the message "Your Ruby version is 2.4.0, but your Gemfile is specified 2.1.2".

I then tried completely removing rvm and reinstalling rbenv. My path is clean of rvm and rbenv appears to properly install ruby 2.1.2. I then did 'gem install rails -v 4.0.3', which was successful and then ran 'gem install bundler' and 'bundle install'. However, I'm still getting the above message regarding Ruby versions. Both 'rbenv version' and 'ruby -v' tell me I'm using 2.1.2. I also tried switching rbenv to 2.4.0 and then back, with the same result. For development reasons I can't switch to Ruby 2.4.0 at this point and have to stick with the Ruby and Rails versions noted.

Here's a cleaner output of echo $PATH

```
/usr/local/bin:  
/Users/user/.rbenv/shims:  
/Users/user/.rbenv/bin:  
/usr/local/bin:  
/usr/local/opt/git/bin:  
/Users/user/.cask/bin:  
/usr/local/heroku/bin:  
/usr/bin:  
/bin:  
/usr/sbin:  
/sbin:  
/usr/local/bin:  
/opt/X11/bin:  
/Library/TeX/texbin:  
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:  
/Users/user/bin:  
/usr/bin:  
/bin:  
/usr/sbin:  
/sbin:  
/usr/local/bin:  
/usr/local/git/bin:  
/usr/texbin:  
/usr/X11/bin:  
/Users/user/android-sdk-mac_x86/tools
```

Comment: If you remove one of `rvm` or `rbenv` you'll probably need to start up a new shell to clear out all the old junk that they set. `which ruby` should indicate which Ruby you're actually using.

Comment: rvm was uninstalled. I've restarted the terminal and the computer. which ruby returns /Users/user/.rbenv/shims/ruby

Comment: Whatever you're using, usually there's a way to find out what instance of a command will be executed without actually triggering it.

Comment: If `which ruby` still returns `.../.rbenv/shims/ruby` then it seems like your path isn't really cleared of some references to rbenv. What's the output of `echo $PATH`?